# Create Rails object with AJAX/Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In a Rails music app, I'm trying to count plays for artists' tracks by creating a `play` object when a visitor to the site plays a track. Each `play` has its own unique ID and belongs to a track.

Currently, I have the create functionality set up in the `plays_controller.rb` file in the API. However, I'm having trouble hooking it up to the play buttons on the page so that playing a track actually creates a new play object which belongs to that particular track.

Users can play tracks in the app using buttons like this:

```
<% @top_tracks.each do |track| %>
  <button class="track-play track-<%= track.id %>-play" onclick="playTrack(<%= track.to_json %>)">
    <i class="icon-play"></i>
  </button>
  ...
  [info about the track, such as <%= track.title %>]
  ...
<% end %>
```

Here are the relevant parts of the `routes.rb` file to show where the `plays_controller.rb` is located in the API:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :plays, only: [:index, :create]
  end
end
```

Here are the relevant parts of the `plays_controller.rb` file:

```
def create
  @play = Play.create!(play_params)
  render(:json => {}, :status => :created)
end

private
def play_params
  params.require(:play).permit(:track_id)
end
```

And here are the relevant parts of the corresponding Javascript:

```
var player = document.getElementById('audio');

window.playTrack = function (track) {
    player.setAttribute('src', track.file_url);
    player.play();

    var trackId = track.id;
};
```

I'm not sure how to use AJAX to properly create a new play object. I've tried adding this to the `playTrack` function in the Javascript above:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/api/v1/plays',
  data: { track_id: trackId }
})
```

But it didn't work and gave me the error message "param not found: play" (which seemed to be thrown from the `play_params` in the `plays_controller.rb` Create action).

Any help getting this working would be much appreciated.

Comment: what's in `play_params` ?

Comment: @Nithin, I showed the `play_params` in the third code snippet, the one from `plays_controller.rb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails expects the params to be nested, e.g. play's track_id should be named `play[track_id]`. You can probably solve this by including a play object in your AJAX data, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/api/v1/plays',
  data: { play: { track_id: trackId } }
})
```